# how to know in code if current request for silverlight is secure or not?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-5.0

Suppose I have silverlight which is hosted on a site call mysite.com.
There are 2 ways to access it either with http or secure with https:

then I want to know in code if this site is accessed with http or https. How to detect it in code behind?

Answer (score 0):

I use: Application.Current.Host.Source.Scheme.Equals("https")